# how to use variable instead of constants

Tags: javascript, iphone, webview, zooming

how to use variable `i` in place of `'1.4'`.i want to use variable `i` to zoom out and zoom in the webview.

```
[tp stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.zoom = '1.4';"];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `NSString` class method [`stringWithFormat:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringWithFormat_)

```
[tp stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = '%f';", i];
```

Comment: %f could well do something completely bogus, depending on the type used to declare i (for instance, as a double).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string using `stringWithFormat:`.

Something like `[tp stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = '%d'", i];`

Comment: I was writing as you posted, Jacob. Sorry about that.

Comment: I also didn't notice it was a float. It should be %f instead of %d.

Answer (score 0):

To use stringWithFormat to create a string that you can pass to stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString, you need to know the type of your scalar variable i.

If it's an int, use '%d'.
If it's a float, use '%f'.
If it's a double use '%lf'.

Or you could cast it to a certain type first:

```
[tp stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = '%lf';", (double)i];
```

Answer (score 0):

[tp stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = '%f';", i]

%f stores i and says it is a float.

On a side note, if you want to specify how many decimals are displayed you would write
%.02f

The zero tells it to pad the number with zeros. The '2' says show 2 decimal places. 
Another example:
If you want three decimal places, use %.03f
If you don't want the padding of zeros, remove the 0.

For 1.4, you would use %.1f